# CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION: Injected projected partition column id must have only (and at least one) equality conditions in the WHERE clause

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue-data-catalog, amazon-athena

Executing this query but having CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION.

*Projection partition applied on id and date.*

```
select * from thermostat_device_telemetry_stats
where id like 'node%'
and "date" = '2022/03/08'
```

**Is there any possibility we can get all records without put projection partition column in where clause?**